# Run laravel migration onto a remote host from a docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, migration, environment-variables, containers

How to reliably run

```
php artisan migrate --env=staging
```

where .env.staging is setup with a remote hostname or ip in the DB_HOST field
OR

```
php artisan migrate --database=staging_db
```

where database.php has a staging_db with DB_HOST pointing to remote hostname or ip

Whenever I run it I receive this error:

> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: No
>   such file or directory    Is the server running locally and accepting 
>     connections on Unix domain socket
>   "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Not sure whats causing it? most likely due to the container being on an internal network which doesnt recognize the remote hostname or IP. How do I solve this?

Comment: can you paste your database.php with 'staging_db' removing your database username and password? I'm looking for hostname and port.
I'm also looking for how you set up your docker, so that the staging_db container is up and running (container name)

Comment: I use psql but same applies to almost every database

database.php
'pgsql' => [
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'stage'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'stage'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'stage'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'schema' => 'public',
    'sslmode' => 'prefer',
],

.env
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=<Your Database Name>
DB_USERNAME=<Your DB User Name>
DB_PASSWORD=<Your User Pass>

Comment: database.docker 
FROM postgres:9.6
COPY ./database/scripts /var/lib/postgresql/util
WORKDIR /var/lib/postgresql/util
docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  database:
    build:
      context: $PATH
      dockerfile: conf.d/database.docker
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
    ports:
      - 5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - $PATH/database/scripts:/var/lib/postgresql/util
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      dev:
        aliases:
          - database_1
          - database_2
volumes:
  data: {}
networks:
  dev:
    external: true

Comment: sorry had to strip out spaces

Comment: ok, it's hard to read. Next time, please paste it in code tags...
In your .env file change the ```DB_HOST=127.0.0.1``` to ```DB_HOST=database``` also i think that ```$PATH``` isn't processed in the docker-compose.yml file

Comment: you cant just blindly use my config. you will need to use mine as an example and get it to work per your requirements